# Excel - Return the cell that end with specific letter from the last hypen

Tags: excel, vba

I have several values in col1. Each value has hyphen in its format. I want to return only those values that has character 'N' as the first letter from the last hyphen.
[image]

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Is it always going to be the last third character starting from the end?

Comment: it is always going to be the after last hypen the first character should be N

Comment: logic we can have is check the hypen from reverse that will be the first hypen from the reverse and check string after that hypen .. if its N return the cell value

Comment: Look into split and left

Comment: If the N will only be after the last hyphen, you can use a simple filter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code for you to try,

```
Sub findN()
Dim i As Long, str As String, j As Long
j = 2
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    str = Replace(Cells(i, 1), "-", "", , (Len(Cells(i, 1)) - Len(Replace(Cells(i, 1), "-", "")) - 1))
    str = Mid(str, InStr(str, "-") + 1, Len(str))
    If Left(str, 1) = "N" Then
        Cells(j, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]